# Remote Logins and SSH: Linux command for overwriting .json file with new data

Tags: c#, .net, linux, ssh, putty

I am trying to read and write data in a Linux machine from another server machine which is Windows OS using a console application exe file, since the Linux machine is accessible only from the server windows machine.

I have read json data from the `.json` file and updated it using the code mentioned below.
Now I want to write the same in the `.json` file by overwriting file with updated data and saving it.

```
try
        {                
            AuthenticationMethod method = new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(appSettings.Value.Username, appSettings.Value.Password);
            ConnectionInfo connection = new ConnectionInfo(appSettings.Value.Host, appSettings.Value.Username, method);
            var client = new SshClient(connection);
            client.Connect();
            if (!client.IsConnected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not Connected...");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connected...");                    
                var readCommand = client.RunCommand("cat /AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/main_copy.json");
                //Console.WriteLine(readCommand.Result);

                dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(readCommand.Result);
                jsonObj["Load_Frequency"] = "Monthly";                    
                string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
                //File.WriteAllText("settings.json", output);--here I need to write code that run Linux command for overwriting .json file with updated data. 
                
                //var writeCommand = client.RunCommand("mkdir \"/home/user/ssh_output\"");
                Thread.Sleep(100000);
            }
        }
```

I tried below command:

```
var writeCommand = client.RunCommand("cat " + output + " > /AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/main_copy.json");
```

But it is showing `No such file or directory` when I execute this command directly in the putty.

Can you help to write linux command for that.

Comment: Try `...RunCommand("echo '" + output + "' >/AAA/....");`. `cat` wants a file name, but you are providing the content of the file already. Be considerate of the length of output. If that can grow arbitrarily, your software will blow up.

Comment: Thanks! It works.